# Bash script for batch removal of php intrusion

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, bash, find

As a beginner with BASH I need some guidance. 
I have 50k+ files across several domains of wordpress, all infected with a php intrusion. I managed to figure out a way to rid the php files of the virus. I just need to get the following script working and got stuck.

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in $(find . -name '*.php.VIRUS');
do
sed -i 's/<?php.*qhepxguxae*?>//g' $file 
mv "$file"  "${file/.VIRUS}"
done
```

Comment: This does not make much sense, sorry. The moment you remove whatever you want to remove your site will get infected again. You have to fix that security hole first, otherwise you will enter a never ending story. The first (and one of the most important things) is to remove the file permissions and make sure that wordpress (php) itself can NOT write its own files. A web application able to modify itself is, well, surprisingly naive from a security point of view.

Comment: What is this script supposed to do? First remove all the contents and then move the (empty) file somewhere else? Let's assume for a moment that what you're trying to achieve really is a viable way to undo the damage*: Why are there already files having the suffix `.php.VIRUS`? Isn't that marker enough to just delete that file, i.e. why do you use `sed` instead of just `rm`? What is the purpose of the `mv` command, i.e. having directories/files like `[...]/index.php.VIRUS/.Virus`? Please elaborate....   *) and then go back to what arkascha wrote ;-)

Comment: I know it's not really a direct answer to your question, but rather than resorting to this, if your site has been hacked, you really should restore from a sane backup. At the very least, you should be sure that you have removed the source of the hack (I guess it can be local).  If you really want to go that route what is the thing that blocks you? any error message you can share?

Comment: thanks for your replies.
@arkascha - yes, first thing will be changing files permiesions to 644 and directories to 755. Also, when my php files are back to normal, i will change administrator passwords, change my hosting, update wordpress and plugins on all my domains and verify if all the plugins are from reliable sources.

Comment: @VolkerK - the script removes only strings of text containing a specific stamp I discovered, which is characteristic to the intrusion. The intrusion is a single line of text, which can be removed with sed command. The .VIRUS extension comes from clamav software my current host uses. The thing is a lot of my php files were locked out by addition of .VIRUS extension so they will not be executed

Comment: @anubhava  - the script seems to be working, I needed to change my scripts permissions and it did the job. Also I ran the scrips through all my .php files so all the nondetected intrusions can be removed

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a script to do this, just use the find tool.

`find /path/to/search -type f -name \*.php -exec sed -i 's/<?php.*qhepxguxae*?>//g' {} \;`